Verification of Asymptotic Expansions using Limits
I am doing a course on Asymptotic Expansions at uni, and we have defined the (Poincaré) asymptotic expansion in the seemingly usual way of:
$(\varphi_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ is an asymptotic sequence at $a$, i.e. $\varphi_{k+1} = o(\varphi_k)$ as $x \to a$ for all $k$.
Then a function $f$ with a limit point at $a$ has an $N$-term asymptotic expansion at $a$ in terms of $(\varphi_k)$ if there exists a sequence of constants $(a_k)_{k=0}^N$ such that $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^N a_i \varphi_i + o(\varphi_N)$, as $x \to a$.
A function $f$ has asymptotic expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \varphi_n$ at $a$ if this holds for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
We then say $f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \varphi_n$. Does this mean the usual definition for $\sim$ holds (i.e. $f\sim g$ as $x\to a$ iff $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)/g(x)) =1).$
Does that mean that I can check if f has a particular asymptotic expansion by computing the limit of $ (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \varphi_n)/f(x)$ as $x\to a$ and seeing if it is $1$?
Sorry for the long winded question, just wanted to make sure my definitions were standard and thanks!

No, it means what you described in the first few paragraphs. Asymptotic equality is different, it just uses the same tilde symbol. The asymptotic expansion is, in many instances, a divergent series anyway.
